# Screen handling fault with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, launcher

My Dell laptop is running 16.04 LTS and was fine up to 28/32.  Since the upgrade to 42/46 the screen handling is now such that when any icon in the Launcher is selected, the whole screen goes blank (back to wallpaper) for some seconds, then the Launcher reappears. This means it is now almost impossible to select any icon and the system is unusable. Has anyone else seen this fault or know the cause?

Comment: It seems to be a fast developing bug. This bug report may fit your description https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1741447

Comment: Yes this bug report seems to cover the problems I am reporting, and I have also seen Compiz crashes.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried this solution and it was effective.

This can be written via terminal ( Ctrl + Alt + T )

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```